# Call Forwarding - Initial call connecting ringtone sounds make line seem engaged

Tags: twilio

Our developers have set up simple call forwarding using Twilio. The problem we're experiencing is outlined as follows:

- Caller rings the number on the listing, which dials Twilio via the local phone network
- The phone network starts to connect the caller with the Twilio number, and while this happens, plays a ringtone
- Twilio responds as fast as it can, but not so soon that no ringtone is never heard, which is why the unwanted "beep"/"ring" tone is heard
- Twilio then shoots off a request to our server to get instruction for what to do next. Only at this point do we have control on how to respond (i.e. prior to that, Twilio hasn't even answered)

This initial "beep" sound is problematic in that the caller may reasonably think the line is engaged or that the dialled number is incorrect.

Twilio direct support wasn't able to shed much light on this. Is there any clever workaround for removing or silencing that initial ringtone, or is it simply something that cannot be controlled within Twilio? Anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What country is the Twilio phone number that your users are calling?  Are you saying that they are hearing a ring back that they won't be familiar with (eg a UK ring back as opposed to as US one?).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Devin. This testing was all done for Hong Kong local numbers.

Update - We managed to successfully remove the initial "beep" by using TwiML Bin, but the PDD connection time was still incredibly long (8+seconds). There was also a slight scratching noise heard in the background during the connection wait which doesn't fill the caller with confidence that it's actually connecting.

End result is we're testing with Nexmo, which has a far shorter connection gap (it's almost instant).